# PrimeFaces Galleria caption internationalization in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, internationalization, galleria

I am using the latest version PrimeFaces 12 Galleria and I want to display the image caption in different languages using the JSF Resource Bundle. I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. The following does not work:

listOfPhotos.add(new Photo("/resources/images/photos/photo1.jpg", "/resources/images/photos/photo1s.jpg",
"Description for Photo 1", "#{bundle.Caption1}"))

It does not recognize the bundle handle and processes the EL statement #{bundle.Caption1} as a String.

How do I get the bundle String and display the caption in different languages?